# MySQL How to do addition in column current value?

Tags: mysql

Anyone can please help me How can I add 2 in Stock_qty and update current value 2 to 4?

[MySQL Columns Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvh34.png)

Comment: @Héctor I don't have an idea so I tried nothing.

Comment: Please refer to the manual which has clear examples of this very thing https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: Please consider to add some code to your question, are you using phpmyadmin?? in that case maybe you just need to click on that record's edit button,,

Comment: Really? It was easier to provide an image than text? :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update tablename set stock_qty =stock_qty+2 where <put the condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update all the columns use like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET Stock_qty= Stock_qty+ 2;
```

it update all the columns of Stock_qty

But if you want to update some columns then use @amal code it is fine

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET Stock_qty= Stock_qty+ 2 WHERE <Condition>;
```

You can refer [documents](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) too